# Redirect to secure area (ssl)

Tags: asp.net, redirect, https

After login, I want to redirect to a secure area with ssl protection on my site. I'm trying this:

```
' After successfull authentication
Dim serverName As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"))

Dim vdirName As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath

Context.Response.Redirect("https://" & serverName & vdirName & "/Restrictedarea/Default.aspx", True)
```

This is working on server but when running local the port number is missing. How do I write the above to work for both online and local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for leading me to the uri builder. I came up with this solution which works me both local (with a port number) and remote.

```
  Private Function pathCombine(ByVal p1 As String, ByVal p2 As String) As String
    Return String.Format("{0}/{1}", p1.TrimEnd.TrimEnd(CChar("/")), p2.TrimStart(CChar("/")))
  End Function

  Private Function getURI(ByVal https As Boolean, ByVal appendPath As String) As UriBuilder
    Dim uri As New UriBuilder

    ' set scheme / protocol
    uri.Scheme = CStr(IIf(https, "https", "http"))

    ' set port
    Dim port As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")
    Select Case port
      Case Nothing, "80", "443"
        uri.Port = -1
      Case Else
        uri.Port = CInt(port)
    End Select

    ' set server / host        
    uri.Host = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"))

    ' set the path
    uri.Path = pathCombine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath, appendPath)

    Return uri
  End Function
```

Two use examples:

---

```
Context.Response.Redirect(getURI(True, "secure/Default.aspx").ToString, True)
```

---

```
Dim uri As New UriBuilder(getURI(True, "secure/Default.aspx").ToString)
uri.Query("foo=bar")
Context.Response.Redirect(uri.ToString, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) to get the information you need